# How to delete a file property google drive

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I try to delete a file property as follows, but the deletion does not occur.

```
            File file = drive.files()
                    .get(fileId)
                    .setFields("properties")
                    .execute();
            Map<String, String> fileProperties = file.getProperties();
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : fileProperties.entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getKey().contains(PermissionTypeEnum.USER.name()) || entry.getKey().contains(PermissionTypeEnum.GROUP.name())
                        || entry.getKey().contains(PermissionTypeEnum.ROLE.name()) || entry.getKey().contains(PermissionTypeEnum.DEPARTMENT.name())) {
                    entry.setValue(null);
                }
            }
            file.setProperties(fileProperties);
            drive.files().update(fileId, file).execute();
```

How do I delete file properties?

Comment: What would happen if you not set entry value to null, but remove the entry from the map?

Comment: Which API version are you using? @TSlak

Comment: I use 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev110-1.23.0'. If I set property null (file.setProperties(null)), properties are not cleared @ale13

Comment: If I set property null (file.setProperties(null)), properties are not cleared @fluffy

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove a specific property for a file using the Drive API v3, you will have to make use of `setAppProperties` method.

According to the Java library for Drive API v3 documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/model/File.html#setAppProperties-java.util.Map-):

> `setAppProperties` > A collection of arbitrary key-value pairs which are private to the requesting app. Entries with null values are cleared in update and copy requests.
>
> Parameters:
> `appProperties` - `appProperties` or null for none

Therefore, you will have to change this line:

```
 file.setProperties(fileProperties);
```

To this:

```
file.setAppProperties(fileProperties);
```

#### Reference

- [Java library for Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/model/File.html#setAppProperties-java.util.Map-).